# Notification body/title RTL android

Tags: push-notification, arabic, android-layout-direction

I want to show notification in Arabic, its title and body is set but in Arabic I need to set title and body to RTL?
How I can do that? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it through custom notification

refer link https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification